# Find last token in stringstream

Tags: c++, token, stringstream

I have a `stringstream` and must find out if it ends with a certain word or not. How do you iterate over the `stringstream` and pick out the last string?

It's a school excercise in which you are not allowed to use iterators or any other magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string stream is kind of like snprintf in C, so you actually convert it to a string via the `.str()` method. This is a basic example: To actually get all the worlds you will have to split on space, and put it into an array or vector, or something.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "self" << ' ' << "world" << ' ' << "bacon";
        std::string str(ss.str());
        std::string buf;

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                buf += str[i];
                if(str[i] == ' ') {
                        buf = "";
                }
        }
        cout << buf << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: But how do I pick out the last word only from the string? This only turns the stringstream into a string.

Comment: Are you allowed to use vectors?

Comment: Why are you using C++ then, if you can't take advantage of all the things that make C++ great. You should stick to C if you can't even use vectors. This is just irritating. If you can't use vectors, then you will need to create a C array of `const char*`'s

Comment: I totally agree!

But as said before, it is a school excercise in which we simply are not allowed to use vectors, iterators etc. That comes later in the course, and our teacher is very strict that we should not use those solutions for the current problems. It kinda kills the creativity :/

Comment: Do you have any information about these "words" what is the total number of possible words inputed into the program?

Comment: For example, if the stringstream cointains "1 2 3 kevin bacon"
the task is to find out if the stream ends with the string "bacon"

Comment: Good luck with your program in 2014. What you have to do is create a lot of boiler-plate code that could easily be solved with standard library functions

Comment: We are allowed to use those features in later excercises. Unfortunatelly not now :/

Comment: Actually, i was over thinking this. My edit solves your problem, all you have to do is add the condition to check for =